# Sending document between two peoples to edit and sign the document in docusign

Tags: docusignapi, docusigncompositetmplts

I need your suggestion/solution to do the following in docusign

Scenario:

--> I need to send the document to a person(Signer), if the signer has no time 
     to fill the document.
 --> He has to send the document to someone to fill the document but not to
     sign.once the second person fill the document he need to send the document 
     to the first person(signer).
 --> Finally the signer review the document if there is any mistake in the 
     filled document he has to correct it and sign.

Kindly provide the solution for this,
Thanks in advance,
Vignesh.B

Comment: Can you please show us what you have tried. What worked and what did not work?

Comment: Please see [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) help page. What have you tried so far, and what errors/issues have you faced? StackOverflow is not a code-writing service. Ideally provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)